# Can't open json files in vscode directly form File Explorer?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Can't even open ps1 files in vscode from File Explorer. With both (json and ps1) I get a tone with no message that I can find. Everything opens fine if I open directly from the "open file" menu item in vscode. I don't think it was like this before installing PowerShell.

Comment: This is not a coding question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a permission error or a bad installation of `vscode`.

I recommend you reinstall `vscode` & make sure to check all these **4** boxes in this image below, we will see how it goes after.

[image: Installation Iamge]

Comment: I so much appreciate your help with VSCode settings. I am also very happy that you got your answer in before my question was closed. A little confused about settings in the Coding environment being off topic for coding? The people over at MSBuild 2020 seem very sure that getting the coding environment setup correctly is a big part of coding. You solved my problem so it is no longer an issue but I would like you to get credit for the answer. If you would like me to change my question so you can be credited just tell me how and I will.

Comment: I'm glad to be able to solve your problem! The answer has been accepted by you I guess, so that's all good. Cheers mate!